# Makefile to compile kernel module to include out of tree source files

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, linux-kernel, cross-compiling

I am new to compiling kernel modules to include out of tree source files using a makefile. I have read a few tutorials and I am still falling short. Without getting too detail I have created a scenario to describe the problem and resulting makefile.

```
dir1/main.c

dir2/subdir2/file.c
dir2/subdir2/include/file.h
```

Below is a resulting makefile

```
obj-m:=main.o
main-y := ../dir2/include/file.o
KDIR := /home/userid/rowboat-android/kernel/
PWD := $(shell pwd)


default:
      $(MAKE) ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/userid/rowboat-android/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-  -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean
      $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
```

Per the scenario described is this Makefile correct?

The reference material talk about ccflags-y and EXTRA_CFLAGS. Can someone please explain the purpose of these switches?

My primary source of references are

1. [Building External Modules](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt)
2. [Linux Kernel Makefiles](http://www.ravnborg.org/kbuild/makefiles.html)
3. Questions and answers on Stackoverflow

Thank you for your time in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Linux documentation](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.11.2/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt#L289):

> ccflags-y specifies options for compiling with $(CC).
>
> ```
>      Example:
>              # drivers/acpi/Makefile
>              ccflags-y := -Os
>              ccflags-$(_ACPI_DEBUG) += -DACPI_DEBUG_OUTPUT
> ```

The ccflags-obj will pass whatever flags are specified the to $(CC)
 when make builds obj.o.  If you use ccflags-y then this acts as a sort of wildcard and passes that flag to all objects being built by the makefile.  Usually this is not relevant to out of tree modules but the effects of these flags are recursive if your Makefile invokes,other Makefiles.

The same documentation says that EXTRA_CFLAGS is the old way of doing the same thing and you shouldn't use it.

Comment: thank you for the response. So based on section 4.3 Several Subdirectories of [Building External Modules](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) by defining ccflags-y := -I$(src)../dir2/subdir2/include/file.h would include the heard file.

Comment: Almost!  `-I` works a little differently.  `-I` tells the compiler where to look for include files that the source files include using the `#include "file.h"` format.  So your statement should be `ccflags-y := -I$(src)../dir2/subsir2/include/` and inside `main.c` and `file.c` you should have an `#include "file.h"` statement.

Comment: I've never used $(src) before, but according to section 3.10 of [Linux Kernel Makefiles](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt) that should be set to the same folder as your Makefile.